# Converting specific time format with strptime

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert

```
[16/Jan/2010:18:11:06 +0100] (common log format)
```

to a timestamp. How can I use `strptime` to convert this?

time zone can be different from +0100

Comment: What code have you tried?  Please post your attempt at using `datetime.datetime.strptime`.  Also, please post any error messages you got when you actually **tried** to do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time
log = '16/Jan/2010:18:11:06 +0100'
dt = time.strptime(log, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S +0100')
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime

Python's timezone support is problematic and platform dependant.
See [this post](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/python-and-time-zones-fighting-the-beast/) (see also its first part).

Comment: im having trouble converting timezone,python only defines named timezones. rest is no problem

Comment: datetime object may be preferable for python 2.5 and beyond